# How disable order confirmation mail

Tags: php, e-commerce, prestashop-1.6

```
$this->module->validateOrder((int)$this->context->cart->id, 27, $total,
    $this->module->displayName, null, array(), null, false, $customer->secure_key);
```

this method in my payment module, for create order, but it send confirmation mail and i cant disable it. Help me.

Comment: I'm also disable order status "Send email to customer" checkbox

Answer (score -1):

If you simply want to disable confirmation emails, then go to:

**Backoffice -> Advanced Parameters -> Email -> Never Send Email**

If you want a custom method, you will have to provide more detail in your question.

Comment: with this on contact page if someone send you a message you will never receive the email !